# Performing "flick" with AppiumDriver.swipe method

Tags: mobile, appium, gesture, java-client

I am using Appium's `java-client 3.2.0 API`; and would like to perform a "flick" gesture. I am guessing I need to use the `swipe()` method for this. My questions are

1. What value should I use as the duration so that the swipe is "fast" enough to be considered as a flick gesture?
2. Does the distance between `start` and `end` point matter?

Answer (score 0):

if duration is fixed, longer distance means faster flick speed;
if distance is fixed, shorter duration means faster flick speed.
You can always set a breakpoint at the flicking point and change different values to see whether it's 'fast' enough.